# Excluding text values from SUMPRODUCT with MOD function

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has people's work hours allocated in columns in 3 shifts, like in the attached image

[image: Table with shifts]

What I need is a formula that will count me hours per shift. I have around 200 people there.

I've been trying to use
    =SUMPRODUCT((MOD(ROW($I$15:$I$225);3)=0)*($I$15:$I$225))

This seems to work fine, with one problem. If I have a text, we usually put "x" when no hours are counted, I get #VALUE. I understand this is to do with multiplication.

Any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the formula slightly:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(ROW($I$15:$I$225);3)=0);($I$15:$I$225))
```

By putting the values in their own space SUMPRODUCT will naturally skip any values that are not numeric.

We still need to change the Boolean values of TRUE/FALSE to their numeric equivalents 1/0.  The `--` before will do that.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However I still get the #Value even after using that. I get the #VALUE no matter where I put the X in, whether in the column that gets counted, or does not

Comment: It works for me.  The only problem I have is when there is an error in the column. @NikolaL.

Comment: @NikolaL. I have provided a screen shot to show it working.

Comment: I found where the error was. I used multiplication sign between the left and the right part of the range. Could you explain why you used the ; instead of *?

Comment: as per the answer `By putting the values in their own space SUMPRODUCT will naturally skip any values that are not numeric.`